# How can we say "Merry Christmas" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I was wondering how can we wish people today a "Merry Christmas" in Latin?

I figured one could say

> felicem natalem Christi

but it's not a literal translation or could be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pope Francis uses [nativitas](https://twitter.com/Pontifex_ln/status/1474356687028961280) for *Christmas* is his Latin tweets, so I would suggest something simple like:

> Felicem Nativitatem Habe / Habete

If you don't want to include the imperative, you could drop *habe* so you're simply making a statement. You could also something more like the Romans did with Saturnalia:

> io Felix Nativitas!

Comment: Hopefully someone will let me know if my declensions are wrong. :)

Comment: The interjection *io!* isn't a generic celebratory interjection, but is strictly associated with the Sāturnālia. While there are many pre-Christian elements in Christmas, introducing new/old 'pagan' elements into Christmas intentionally would be an ideological move.

Answer (score 1):

The closest actual Latin equivalent would be something like

> frui saturnalia

which (some people argue) is the ancient roman festivities that later evolved into what is today christmas.

You could argue that most people wouldn't understand the reference, but then again most people don't understand Latin, and those who do, probably will.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you edit your answer to elaborate on what this means more literally and where you found it? This is not the typical Saturnalia greeting I've seen.

Comment: Even if Saturnalia eventually evolved into Christmas, it is still a different holiday, so I'm not sure this is such a good fit.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: god Jul!

Comment: I had learned in latin class (a long time ago), about the historical link between the modern Christmas celebration and the Roman Saturnalia holiday. `io saturnalia` was the phrase my teacher used in class.

Comment: I'm afraid this reply is incorrect. *fruī* means "to make use of, enjoy" and isn't used in wishes; you put it in the infinitive, which isn't used in wishes - you need the 2p. imperative *fruere*; this verb commands its object in the ablative, so *sāturnāliīs*. Finally, as others have mentioned, the Sāturnaliā is a different holiday from Christmas and belongs to a different religion. It's never used to refer to the birth of Christ, and will be considered sacrilegious.